# Creating a SQL instance on GCP and setting Private services access?

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I`m setting up a SQL instance on GCP, when configuring the options I want to choose a network path for connecting to this instance. I want to choose private IP:

[image]

### So I`m trying to set up the private IP connection :

[image]

### Choose default-ip-range:

[image]

### And get the error:

[image]

### So I tried to set up a manual connection with:

[image]
[image]

### And again the error:

[image]

So I tried option **use automatically allocated IP range** and it just wants to reconnect to the existing dafeault_ip_range and I get the error:  `The resource 'projects/[myProject]/global/addresses/default-ip-range' already exists`

Don't know what else to try...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to fix this issue. Either way, the objective is to allocate the respective IP ranges to the private connection.

First, using CLI Command, which will call update connection with new ranges and force flag to change the ranges used for the connection:

```
gcloud services vpc-peerings update --network=default --ranges=new-ip-range-4,default-ip-range --service=servicenetworking.googleapis.com --force
```

Or second, navigate to Google Cloud Platform > VPC Network > VPC Network Details > Private Service Connection > Private Connections to Services.  [Modify](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-private-services-access#modifying-connection) the private connection with the desired IP ranges

For example in the UI, it should look like this[image]

Comment: is it possible to use only `new-ip-range-4` and NOT use `default-ip-range` in the modification? If so, how can we delete the allocation safely. Its bit not clear in the documentation.

Comment: Using similar command as provided in answer results in error "Allocated IP range 'default-ip-range' not found in network" even though 'default-ip-range' is being used sql instances