# How to workaround the 100 active connections limit between each Cloud Run container and Cloud SQL instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I use Cloud Run and connect to Cloud SQL via the native connector, where I just specify the instance connection name and Cloud Run exposes it inside as a UNIX socket. The problem is that there is a limit of 100 active SQL connections imposed on each Cloud Run container instance.

My only question is: If I, instead, use a VPC serverless access connector and through that connect Cloud Run to the Cloud SQL instance via internal IP, would the limit continue to be imposed? Wouldn't this limit just be imposed on the Cloud Run native SQL connector?

Answer (score 2):

That limit is only due to the Cloud Run Cloud SQL connector. You can use a serverless VPC connector and go beyond that limit.

But Cloud SQL has a also a [limit in number of connections](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/quotas#cloud-sql-for-mysql-default-connection-limits) and I'm not sure that opening so much connection on only one Cloud Run instance is a good choice.

In addition, if you use connection pool, you can reuse your connections easily and it could be better to scale horizontally with Cloud Run, instead of having only 1 big CLoud Run instance with thousands of connections to a database.

Comment: We're using sqlalchemy pool, with pool size of 7, but often we receive "Exceeded maximum of 100 connections per instance". Is there any reason this might be happening. We don't make detached connections (connections outside of pool). Can you please suggest any approach to debug & fix this issue?

Comment: I don't know how work SQL Alchemy. I don't know if it close the connections when the container is offloaded. If not, you should try to add a listener on the sigkill event to release the connection when the container is killed.

Comment: After a futile attempt to prevent this connection limitation, resorted to using VPC connectors to connect with cloud SQL instances which led to another blocker. While creating SQL instances (2 in total, MySQL & Postgres), missed setting up private IP. While adding private IP now, we're unable to set "Allocated IP range" as it can be set only during instance creation. After creating private IP in MySQL, we're now unable to create private IP for postgres, as we receive `Couldn't find free blocks in allocated IP ranges` error. Can you please suggest any fix here?

Comment: saw a possible solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68635477/creating-a-sql-instance-on-gcp-and-setting-private-services-access). is it possible to use only `new-ip-range-4` and NOT use `default-ip-range` in the modification? If so, how can we delete the `default-ip-range` allocation safely.